# Bi-Directional Mapping Error : Could not determine type

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to implement Many-To-One and One-To-Many bi-directional mapping on Room Transfer and Room Department Mapping class using `nRoomAllocationId`.

**RoomTransfer  class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="roomtransfer")
public class RoomTransfer implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ntrans_id",columnDefinition="serial")
    public Integer nTransId;

    @Column(name="nroom_allocation_id")
    public Integer nRoomAllocationId;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="badd_transfer_bln")
    public boolean bAddTransferBln=true;

    @Column(name="dtrans_date")
    public LocalDate dTransDate;

    @Column(name="bis_active")
    public boolean bIsActive=true;  

    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "nroom_allocation_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public RoomDepartmentMapping roomDepartmentMapping;
```

**RoomDepartmentMapping  Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="roomdepartmentmapping")
public class RoomDepartmentMapping implements Serializable{ 

    @Id 
    @Column(name="nroom_allocation_id")
    public Integer nRoomAllocationId;

    @Column(name="nroom_id")
    public Integer nRoomId; 

    @Column(name="bis_manual")
    public Boolean bIsManual;   

    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "nroom_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public Room room;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="roomDepartmentMapping", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<RoomTransfer> roomTransfer;
```

**Error**

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: roomdepartmentmapping, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(room_transfer)]
```

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong in mapping?

Answer (score 0):

Your fields are `public`. JPA spec does not allow that:

> The instance variables of a class must be private, protected, or
>   package visibility independent of whether field access or property
>   access is used. When property access is used, the property accessor
>   methods must be public or protected.

Comment: I used protected but not working I am getting error in console :`at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar`

Comment: thats not a jpa error. That is jackson way up the controller. The orm seems to be fine now?

Comment: You'll need to provide more code/context - why and how are your beans being serialized? Are they going directly to a controller and being 'converted' into (e.g.) JSON?

Comment: thats outside of context of this question. This is just another problem.